# Divi Theme Featured Image of post in admin panel keeps loading

Tags: wordpress, themes, loading, divi

I have integrated Divi theme in a website. In the posts "Featured Image" panel keeps loading. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2sL5.png. The image is not displayed in frontend and other images are also broken. Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my this issue. I added featured image using Divi theme page builder. It successfully added the images and displayed in frontend.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the **Divi > Theme Options > Support Center > Enable the Safe Mode** because sometimes 3rd party plugin cause these kind of issues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried this way but it did not worked for me